# How can I automatically logout users connected to the console session of a Windows Server 2008 R2 box via VNC?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have a server that people use VNC viewer to connect to as it has a security dongle for a 3rd party piece of software which does not support virtualization or remote desktop/terminal services.

I need to set things up so that when users connect they're automatically logged out after 15 minutes of inactivity. I know how to do this for users who are connected via Remote Desktop/Terminal Services but since they're connected to the console I'm not sure this will work the same way.

Is there another way to go about logging users out connected directly to the console session via VNC?

The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that RealVNC has an advanced option for this, called `IdleTimeout` :

> **IdleTimeout**
>   This setting tells WinVNC how many seconds a connected
>   VNC client may remain idle for (no input events or update requests)
>   before being disconnected. If this setting is not specified or is set
>   to zero then no timeout is enforced. Local or Global per-user setting

This parameter has to be defined in Windows Registry at :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ORL\WinVNC3\Default`

Further reading in the [documentation](http://www.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/vnc/winvnc.html#4).

Comment: We have TightVNC installed but this may very well be an option with TightVNC as well. Thanks for the pointer. I'll award the answer once confirmed!

Comment: It seems that this also applies to TightVNC : http://www.forwestmedia.com/resources/how-to-guides/tightvnc-installation-and-use/#tvnc3

Comment: Our system doesn't seem to have this registry key (or anything for ORL) but this is a good enough answer for most people so I'll go ahead and give you the check. Thanks!